# meta does not work when using get on a splayed table

Tags: kdb

I have seen this question, but I think my issue is a bit different :
[kdb splayed table meta error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163816/kdb-splayed-table-meta-error)

I am saving a table splayed in a location with the following command :

`pthToSplayed upsert .Q.en[pthtohdbroot;] table`

I don't have any `sym` so nothing gets enumerated (.Q.en is there because in the future it might have some symbols).

All works well, but when I try to do `meta select from get[pathToTable] where date = .z.d` I get a `..sym` error.

However, the strange part is that the first time I am saving the table down ... the meta works fine. when I exit and start the proc again the problem seems to appear. what exactly happens here? I would appreciate links to a whitepaper or kx website which explains where this issue comes from.

**UPDATE**:
Nothing weird about the meta of the table. just a vanilla meta.

`` `:/home/user/hdbroot/tableName/ set .Q.en[`:/home/user/hdbroot;] table ``

As I am updating this table I am using upsert instead of set for subsequent operations.

Comment: Hi, can you give a little bit more information: can you show the meta of your `table`, can you show (approximately) what `pthToSplayed`, `pthtohdbroot` and `pathToTable` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the enumeration file named `sym` needs to be loaded in to the process memory.

If you load the folder using `\l` you will not have the issue:

```
q)\l hdbRoot
```

Or you can explicitly load the sym file:

```
q)tableName:get `:hdbRoot/tableName/
q)sym:get `:hdbRoot/sym
```

The reason it works before a restart is because `.Q.en` automatically loads `sym` in to memory for you when you call it.

If there are no symbol columns there should be no error.

Save table with no symbol column:

```
$q
q)`:hdbRoot/tableName/ set .Q.en[`:hdbRoot] ([] a:1 2 3)
`:hdbRoot/tableName/
q)\\
```

New session `meta` works:

```
$q
q)tableName:get `:hdbRoot/tableName/
q)meta tableName
c| t f a
-| -----
a| j
```

You can check the types of each column to confirm there are no enumerations:

```
q)type each flip tableName
```

Prior to V3.6 of kdb+, the type of an enumeration could range from 20h to 76h, with each new domain given an incremented type. In V3.6 onwards all enumerations 20h

If any column is a symbol type, even if empty then a `sym` file is created:

```
q)`:hdbRoot/tableName/ set .Q.en[`:hdbRoot] ([] a:`long$();b:`$())
`:hdbRoot/tableName/
q)get `:hdbRoot/sym
`symbol$()
```

Comment: but the sym file is not even created because there are no symbol columns in the table

Comment: I added code to the answer so you can check and confirm you have no symbol type columns.